# how to pass data to Angular ng-bootstrap modal

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, ng-bootstrap

I think I'm missing something but cannot figure what.
Basically I'm trying to pass an object to the modal like below, but instead of getting the passed object I gets null...so I think is a problem with the scope but I'm new in Angular and need some help.

component.html:

```html
            <tbody>
              <tr *ngFor="let user of userList">
                <!-- <th scope="row">{{ind}}</th> -->
                <th scope="row">{{ user.id }}</th>
                <td>{{user.name}}</td>
                <td>{{user.username}}</td>
                <td>{{user.password}}</td>
                <td>{{user.role}}</td>
                <td>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="openModal(editUserModal, user)">Edit</button>
                
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<ng-template #editUserModal let-modal>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="editUserModal">Edit Profile</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" (click)="modal.dismiss()" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-body">
    <form [formGroup]="editUserForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="name" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="name" id="name">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="username" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Username</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="username" id="username">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="password" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Password</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" formControlName="password" id="password">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="role" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Role</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="role" id="role">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="modal.dismiss()">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

component.ts

```typescript
ngOnInit() {

    this.editUserForm = this.fb.group({
      name: new FormControl(null, []),
      username:new FormControl(null, []),
      password: new FormControl(null, []),
      role:new FormControl(null, [])

    });
}

  openModal(targetModal, user) {
    this.modalService.open(targetModal, {
      centered: true,
      backdrop: 'static'
    });

    this.editUserForm.patchValue({
      name: user.name,
      username: user.username,
      password: user.password,
      role: user.role

    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.modalService.dismissAll();
    console.log("res:", this.editUserForm.getRawValue());
  }
```

ng-bootstral 6.0.1, Angular 9.0.1

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are trying to do and what exactly your issue is. What object are you trying to pass?

Comment: I want to pass to data from table to ng bootstrap modal but i can't find what i am missing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the attempt to pass the data in the code provided. Here is the manual: [How to pass data to and receive from NG Bootstrap modals](https://medium.com/@izzatnadiri/how-to-pass-data-to-and-receive-from-ng-bootstrap-modals-916f2ad5d66e). It should help you.

Comment: It says how to pass data to `NgbModal`, if its markup is a separate component. All internet examples are the same. But there is no information how to pass data to `NgbModal`, if its markup is a part of current markup, i.e. `<ng-template #modalContent>`... I've tried to use the same approach, but it does not work.